# Java Program runs but gives no output

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guys i was working on a project and the output gives nothing. I already tried a bunch of things which all gave no output except for moving System.out.print above the brace which just printed out an infinite number of random numbers. It's a short code so here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class ACSLPrintsJR {
public static int value(int num){
int [] array = {0,16,16,8,8,4,4,2,2,1,1};
    return array[num];
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int top = 1;
    int bottom = 1;
    File file = new File("ACSLPRINTSJR.IN");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    while (num != 0){
    num = scan.nextInt();
        if (num % 2 == 0)
            top += 1 + value(num);
        else 
            bottom += 1 + value(num);
    }       
    System.out.println(top+"/"+bottom);
scan.close();
}

}
```

As i said there is no output and here is the content of the IN file

Input is:

> 8 7 2 0
>
> 0

Expected output is:

> 19/3
>
> 1/1

Current output:
Nothing

Comment: You need to keep updating `num` in the while loop using `num = scan.nextInt()`.

Comment: Walk through your code on paper to see what it's doing in that loop.  If you did this, you'd see that it never gets data from the Scanner.

Comment: I did that and now it actually outputs something but it isn't the right output and it only does it for one line

Comment: It's odd that you have multiple lines of input, but your while loop ends after the first `0` is encountered.

Comment: i edited my code to the one that returns 5/4

Comment: is there a way i could make it end just that line at 0 instead of the whole loop?

Comment: because we are supposed to stop reading the line when it reaches 0 then move to the next input line

Comment: Then you need to re-think your approach, one while loop that ends once the first `0` is encountered is not going to read multiple lines. Have you considered using a nested while loop, the outer while loop would run while `scan.hasNextLine()` and the inner would run while `num != 0`. There are of course caveats to this approach, for instance after `0` has been encountered you would need to call `scan.nextLine()` and you would have to account for blank lines.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan i will try it out

Comment: @JonnyHenly Doing a nested while loop worked except that the bottom is one larger than it should be

Comment: oh also if you have more than one line then it doesn't run at all

Comment: could you [edit] your question to include the expected and current output.

Comment: Ok the input and expected output and current output are in the decription

Comment: Heads up, I think your expected output for the first run should be `21/4`. (Top would be: `1+1+array[8]+1+array[2]` = `1+1+2+1+16` = 21. Bottom: `1+1+array[7]` = `1+1+2` = 4.)

Comment: The expected output was 19/3 in the project, the reason it looked like it wasn't is because of a mistake i made,  top and bottom are the array value of the num plus one but the way i had it was +2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read from scanner in the loop. Below is updated code for you.

```
public class ACSLPrintsJR {
    public static int value(int num) {
        int[] array = {0, 16, 16, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1};
        return array[num];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("ACSLPRINTSJR.IN");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        int num;
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int top = 1;
            int bottom = 1;
            while ((num = scan.nextInt()) != 0) {
                if (num % 2 == 0)
                    top += value(num);
                else
                    bottom += value(num);
            }
            System.out.println(top + "/" + bottom);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: ill add that into the description

Comment: k i added it to the desc.

Comment: updated per your output. This gives the exact result what you need. Hope you are looking for this.

Comment: This works thanks, i also noticed why doing 1+ was wrong after seeing this. I will give you correct answer

Comment: yep this solves it, I used the same approach but kept getting the wrong answers. Then I saw that you didn't add 1 to top or bottom. +1

Comment: Great to hear that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an infinite loop here:

```
int num = scan.nextInt();
while (num != 0){
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        top += 1 + value(num);
    else 
        bottom += 1 + value(num);
}       
System.out.println(top+"/"+bottom);
```

You read in `num` from your file, and if `num` is not zero, the loop runs infinitely, because you never modify the value of `num` in your while loop. I would venture to guess that you need to say:

```
int num = scan.nextInt();
do{
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        top += 1 + value(num);
    else 
        bottom += 1 + value(num);

    num = scan.nextInt();
}while(num != 0);
System.out.println(top+"/"+bottom);
```

However, I do not know the exact intent of your code, so this might not be the desired approach. Point is, though, you need to modify `num` in your while loop or else you will loop infinitely.

Comment: does do mean that it does things inside of it's braces while num !=0?

Comment: i changed it to do but it still returns 5/4

Comment: @icecreeper01, a `do-while` loop is a loop where the first iteration is executed before the condition (`num != 0` in this case) is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The num variable never changes its value and i think that you've to do this for every line in your file. You've to update your while guard like `while(scan.hasNextInt())` so you can keep going until there's an int value in your file and then you pick it using `scan.nextInt()`. The rest of the code is basically the same. I saw now your edit so now if the value that you pick with `scan.nextInt()' is equals to 0 you've to print what you need, reset your counter variables and keep going into the loop until you'll pick the last 0 in your file. I hope i'm enough clear.